# $A$ has empty interior iff $A^c$ is dense in M.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a set in a metric space $M$.

**Proof**:

Assume $A^c$ is dense in M $\iff$ $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A^c $ for all $x \in M$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ $\iff$ for all $x' \in A$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, $\ B_{\epsilon}(x') \cap A^c \neq \emptyset \iff$ there is no $B_{\epsilon}(x') \subset A$ for any $x' \in A$ and every $\epsilon > 0 \iff A^o$ is empty.

I am not sure if I can prove the equivalence in one go like this. I should note that I believe that $A^c = M \setminus A$ so it is trivial to show that for $x \notin A$ the epsilon ball around $x$ intersects $A^c$.

**EDIT**: $\iff$ for $x' \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we cannot find $B_{\epsilon}(x') \subseteq A$.

Comment: you should phrase "there is no $B_\epsilon(x') \subset A$ for any $x' \in A$ and every $\epsilon > 0$" more clearly in order to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Should I say like, "for a point $x' \in A$?"

Comment: "it's not the case that there is some $x' \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$ with $B_\epsilon(x') \subseteq A$"

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you very much sir, or madam.

Comment: your edit is still ambiguous / wrong

Comment: Would you be so kind as to point out the ambiguity? I still have troubling writing rigorous proofs. I understand it needs concise language, so if I know where I err I could better edit it. I also would not just want to copy what you have, but rather try to see if I understand the error myself but rewording it. Thank you.

Comment: you wrote "there exists no $x′ \in A$ s.t. for any $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(x') \subseteq A$". But this is not what you meant. For example, in $(0,1)$, there does not exist $x'$ s.t. $B_\epsilon(x') \subseteq (0,1)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, since we could consider $\epsilon = 2$. English gets confusing when you use negations. That's why it's always best to say "it's not the case that ..."

Comment: Okay, okay, I see. Since, my previous edit would imply that, for instance, $(0,1)$ is empty! I'll take heed of your warning. Thank you for the help.